# Faster collisions and begincontact in Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision

I'm using libgdx & box2d. Anybody have a problem in faster collisions? because sometimes begincontact is not working. What else can i use for that? i see somewhere that ı should use postsolve but postsolve is not recognizing the collision. my code is below for collision detection.

```
@Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

            Body body = fixtureA.getBody();
            Body body2 = fixtureB.getBody();

if (body2.getUserData().equals(stars10sprite)
                    && body.getUserData().equals(ballsprite)) {
                System.out.println("star 10");
                ballBody = body;
                if (body2 != null)
                    startToRemove.add(body2);
            } 
}
```

I've already tried to change body2 to body to be sure if bodies are reversing. And i've another stars like stars50, stars25 in post solve. code here is the clear one.

Comment: Faster collisions? What is that supposed to mean? Do you mean very fast moving bodies? In this case try to set the `bullet` flag.

Comment: yes i mean faster moving bodies. thanks for the reply, i'll search for a bullet flag.

Comment: I've put the collision code inside begincontact again and set the ball bodyDef as bullet. But still got the same problem on fast moving bodies collision.

Comment: Are you using sensor fixtures? Sensor fixtures will not care about bullet body settings because there is no collision response to do, and the point of the bullet setting is to get the collision in the right place. Try using bullet bodies, with non-sensor fixtures. You can skip the collision response in PreSolve by doing contact->SetEnabled(false) if you want the fast body to pass right through.

Comment: the main character is ball in the game and its dynamic body, and i've set it as bullet. Bullet is colliding with kynematic bodies. Kynematic bodies are always moving around with setvelocity. maybe flagging as a bullet is not a good solution for this situation. I'm still searching.

Comment: any solutions, I got the same problem